# any library to check marathon deployment status

Tags: mesos, marathon, mesosphere

I have a bunch of marathon docker tasks that are run on our test deployment machines.

There is a Jenkins CI job, that triggers the deployment a whole bunch of docker containers that are run on marathon-mesos cluster. (3 mesos-slaves, 1 master and 1 marathon.)

There is another downstream jenkins job (a automated test suite) that is triggered after above job. Presently, we wait for sufficient time, so that deployment gets completed then only we proceed with this automation testsuite. I want to change this behavior. I know marathon exposes rest APIs using which I can determine if I am good to go - after all the containers are deployed and all health checks are passing - for running the automation test suite.

Question is: Is there any library already out there for marathon, that I can reuse to accomplish above task ? I do not want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

When I posted this question, I had java library actually in mind, but forgot to mention that. I find @michael 's libraries are also very good. But this is what I settled upon. Marathon-client. I think I saw this, while browsing through [mesosphere](https://github.com/mesosphere) repositories but somehow missed it.

This is the library: [marathon-client](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-client)

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully been using the two following libs:

- Go: [gambol99/go-marathon](https://github.com/gambol99/go-marathon)
- Python: [thefactory/marathon-python](https://github.com/thefactory/marathon-python)

Comment: Thank you Michael for responding.